# Probabilities with cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Compute the probability that a group of 5 cards drawn at random from a 52 card deck will contain exactly two pair?

There are 13 types of cards. 4 of each.

I honestly shouldn't show how I did it, cuz it's a complete mess with hundreds of solutions. I don't know the answer by the way.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  A hand with two pairs consists of two ranks from which two cards are drawn and a third rank from which one card is drawn.

Choose two ranks from which the pairs will be drawn.  Choose two cards from each of those ranks.  Choose a third rank from which the other card in the hand will be drawn.  Choose one card from that rank.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to measure the probability for selecting *two* from *four* suits in *each* of *two* from *thirteen* kinds, and *one* from *four* suits in *one* from the *eleven* other kinds, when selecting *five* from *fifty-two* cards?

Recall that ${\binom {n}{r}}$ counts the ways to select $r$ from a set of $n$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

We can do it using the multiplication rule:

- decide two numbers to form two pairs: $\mathrm C^{13}_2$, denote as $A$ and $B$
- from the four $A$ cards, choose two cards to form a pair, $\mathrm C^4_2$
- do the same for $B$
- from the remaining 11 numbers, choose one to have a single card $\mathrm C^{11}_1$, denote as $C$
- from the 4 C's, choose one, $\mathrm C^4_1$

(The final two steps can be combined into one step: from the remaining 44 = 52-4-4 cards, choose one)

Multiply all these numbers you get the total number of valid combinations.

Total number of choices without restrictions: $\mathrm C^{52}_5$.

Take the ratio you get the probability.

---

The result should read:
$$ \frac{\mathrm C^{13}_2\times \mathrm C^4_2 \times \mathrm C^4_2 \times \mathrm C^{11}_1 \times \mathrm C^4_1}{\mathrm C^{52}_5}$$

Comment: What do I do with one of those 44 cards? Add 44 to the denominator?

Comment: @Mantas To the numerator. It contributes to the valid choices and is part of the multiplication procedure. To not confuse you, please ignore that bracket. Use the list only.